# Running cross platform C++ code using Visual Studio 2015 Cross-Platform

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++, opengl-es, visual-studio-2015, cross-platform

I am simply trying to get a basic app(s) running on my mobile device(s) using **Visual Studio 2015**'s *cross-platform* capabilities.

I am following the tutorial [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vcblog/2015/07/30/cross-platform-code-sharing-with-visual-c/) to a T. 
It is a small OpenGL ES sample that is suppose to build for **Android**, **iOS**, and **Windows**. The solution has *four* projects: *one* per platform, and *one* shared library. Inside this shared library, there is code that references the OpenGL ES headers.

However, I can's seem to get Visual Studio to know where the OpenGL ES libraries/headers are. (I'm not sure where the headers are suppose to be located either).

Has anyone tried to setup this tutorial project with any success?
How can I tell Visual Studio where the OpenGL ES headers are? (*also, where are they?!?!*) Do I have to tell visual studio something different for each project type? (one per device).

Note the squiggly lines all over the place in the screenshot.

I'm at a loss here. The docs seem to be completely missing this section, and the example template simply doesn't work out of the box.

[image: Visual Studio 2015 Cross Platform Missing headers]

Comment: If you get no joy on SO, try the MSDN Visual Studio Setup forums: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/home?forum=vssetup

Answer (score 1):

The example template works for me out of the box--at least, it builds. Did you give up when you saw the squiggles? Broken intellisense is a fact of life in visual studio since the inception of visual studio. My squiggles all went away when I changed the solution platform from x86 to ARM.  I assume, because android wants to build on the ARM platform. Initially on my system, even `<vector>` was squiggled. But, in both cases--it built.

As for where the headers come from, if you assume the template isn't garbage, the openGL headers are clearly included from one of `pch.h`, `SimpleRenderer.h`, or `MathHelper.h`. Checking each of these is but a moment's work.

Answer (score -1):

try to unload static libs for ios and android. it seems vs gets confused with all the projects loaded.